# Present perfect been/ gone: to or in?

Tags: present-tense, perfect-constructions, been-vs-gone

Do we ask

> Has he ever been to Germany?

OR

> Has he ever gone to Germany?

OR

> Has he ever been in Germany?

Negative:

> He has never gone to Germany.

OR

> He has never been in Germany.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, we say all of those things. I'm not sure what your question actually is.

Answer (score 1):

**All of the sentences you suggest are correct and acceptable.**

There are some trivial distinctions in meaning, but for virtually any usage you can use either of them.